# How to map one entity to different table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

There is my class **TableOne.java**:

```
@Table(name = "table_one")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TableOne {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    @Column(name = "status_desc")
    private String statusDesc;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(table = "callers")
    private Party caller;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(table = "callee")
    private Party callee;

    ...getter/setter
}
```

And there is **Part.java**:

```
@Entity
public class Party {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name = "ip")
    private String ip;

    @Column(name = "port")
    private int port;
}
```

The following fields: caller, callee inside **TableOne.java** contains the same fields (id,desc, port, ip), so I want to keep these in two different tables. For example inside `callee` and `caller` tables.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two entities for that. Simply remove `@Entity` annotation from `Party` and annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass`. Then you can create two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "caller")
public class Caller extends Party
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "callee")
public class Callee extends Party
```

Both will have the same fields, but will be mappet to two different tables.

Comment: Yes, It is the good way to solve my problem, also it is works okey. Thank you! But I can't create a lot of entitys. Have we any other way here? Might I should use @SecondaryTables?

Comment: @ArtemDanilin no, you can compose an entity from 2 tables, here you would have 3: `table_one`, `caller`, `callee`